# Magento 1: Error Creating a Customer Attribute

Tags: magento-1.8, php, attributes, customer-attribute

I'm trying to create a `Wholesale: Yes/No` drop down attribute on customer accounts in the admin. After creating my module and install script, I get the following error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'mycompany_wholesale_setup' for key 'PRIMARY'

Here is what I tried:

> app/etc/modules/**Mycompany_Wholesale.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
        <modules>
            <Mycompany_Wholesale>
                <active>true</active>
                <codePool>local</codePool>
                <version>0.1.0</version>
            </Mycompany_Wholesale>
        </modules>
    </config>
```

---

> app/code/local/Mycompany/Wholesale/etc/**config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
        <modules>
            <Mycompany_Wholesale>
                <version>0.1.0</version>
            </Mycompany_Wholesale>
        </modules>
        <global>
            <resources>
                <mycompany_wholesale_setup>
                    <setup>
                        <module>Mycompany_Wholesale</module>
                        <class>Mage_Customer_Model_Entity_Setup</class>
                    </setup>
                    <connection>
                        <use>core_setup</use>
                    </connection>
                </mycompany_wholesale_setup>

                <Mycompany_Wholesale_write>
                    <connection>
                        <use>core_write</use>
                    </connection>
                </Mycompany_Wholesale_write>

                <Mycompany_Wholesale_read>
                    <connection>
                        <use>core_read</use>
                    </connection>
                </Mycompany_Wholesale_read>
            </resources>
        </global>   
    </config>
```

---

> app/code/local/Mycompany/Wholesale/sql/mycompany_wholesale_setup/**mysql4-install-0.1.0.php**

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');

$entityTypeId     = $setup->getEntityTypeId('customer');
$attributeSetId   = $setup->getDefaultAttributeSetId($entityTypeId);
$attributeGroupId = $setup->getDefaultAttributeGroupId($entityTypeId, $attributeSetId);

$setup->addAttribute("customer", "wholesale",  array(
    "type"     => "int",
    "backend"  => "",
    "label"    => "Wholesale",
    "input"    => "select",
    'source'   => 'eav/entity_attribute_source_boolean',
    "visible"  => true,
    "required" => false,
    "default"  => "",
    "frontend" => "",
    "unique"   => false,
    "note"     => "Wholesale"
));

        $attribute   = Mage::getSingleton("eav/config")->getAttribute("customer", "wholesale");


$setup->addAttributeToGroup(
    $entityTypeId,
    $attributeSetId,
    $attributeGroupId,
    'wholesale',
    '999'  //sort_order
);

$used_in_forms=array();

$used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_customer";
//$used_in_forms[]="checkout_register";
//$used_in_forms[]="customer_account_create";
//$used_in_forms[]="customer_account_edit";
//$used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_checkout";
        $attribute->setData("used_in_forms", $used_in_forms)
                ->setData("is_used_for_customer_segment", true)
                ->setData("is_system", 0)
                ->setData("is_user_defined", 1)
                ->setData("is_visible", 1)
                ->setData("sort_order", 100)
                ;
        $attribute->save();    

$installer->endSetup();
```

Any idea what I did wrong or how I can fix the Duplicate entry error?  I should also note that I don't have direct access to the DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this Code

in your **config.xml** file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Mycompany_Wholesale>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Mycompany_Wholesale>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <helpers>
      <wholesale>
        <class>Mycompany_Wholesale_Helper</class>
      </wholesale>
    </helpers>
    <models>
      <wholesale>
        <class>Mycompany_Wholesale_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>wholesale_mysql4</resourceModel>
      </wholesale>
    </models>
    <resources>
      <customerattribute_setup>
        <setup>
          <module>Mycompany_Wholesale</module>
          <class>Mage_Customer_Model_Entity_Setup</class>
        </setup>
        <connection>
          <use>core_setup</use>
        </connection>
      </customerattribute_setup>
      <customerattribute_write>
        <connection>
          <use>core_write</use>
        </connection>
      </customerattribute_write>
      <customerattribute_read>
        <connection>
          <use>core_read</use>
        </connection>
      </customerattribute_read>
    </resources>
  </global>
</config>
```

and in your install file **customerattribute_setup/mysql4-install-0.1.0.php**

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();


$installer->addAttribute("customer", "wholesale",  array(
    "type"     => "int",
    "backend"  => "",
    "label"    => "Wholesale",
    "input"    => "select",
    "source"   => "eav/entity_attribute_source_boolean",
    "visible"  => true,
    "required" => false,
    "default" => "",
    "frontend" => "",
    "unique"     => false,
    "note"       => ""

    ));

$attribute   = Mage::getSingleton("eav/config")->getAttribute("customer", "wholesale");


$used_in_forms=array();

$used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_customer";
        $attribute->setData("used_in_forms", $used_in_forms)
        ->setData("is_used_for_customer_segment", true)
        ->setData("is_system", 0)
        ->setData("is_user_defined", 1)
        ->setData("is_visible", 1)
        ->setData("sort_order", 100)
        ;
        $attribute->save();



$installer->endSetup();
```

Please note, I used **customerattribute_setup** instead of **mycompany_wholesale_setup**, So you only need to adjust this as you wish

Comment: Thank you, that worked and I kept it as you wrote using `customerattribute_setup`